# Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

These are the statments i got after running the grunt serve command from the directory sangam

```
C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\GitHub\sangam>grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "env:all" (env) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

Running "injector:scripts" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting js files (14 files)
>> Nothing changed

Running "injector:css" (injector) task
Missing option `template`, using `dest` as template instead
Injecting css files (5 files)
>> Nothing changed

Running "wiredep:target" (wiredep) task

Running "autoprefixer:dist" (autoprefixer) task

Running "express:dev" (express) task
Starting background Express server
Debugger listening on port 5858
module.js:327
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Rohit\Documents\GitHub\sangam\node_modules\mongoose\lib\drivers\node-mongodb-native\objectid.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)

Running "wait" task
>> Waiting for server reload...
Done waiting!

Running "open:server" (open) task

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

after running grunt serve , I get that error

> "cannot find module 'mongodb/node_modules/bson'" ,

the localhost page opens , but I get " cant reach this page" , please help me with this

Comment: Refer the [github-link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2718)

Comment: i'm new to this, i went through the github link , but couldn't understand, can you please put it in simple words how to do it in windows cmd , ? @titi23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As written in the [github-issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2718) try doing following steps:-

> Make sure these two packages are at these versions
>
> "mongodb": "^2.1.16",
>   "mongoose": "^4.4.12"

```
npm install -g node-gyp 
cd /to/your/project-folder
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```

Also try doing :-

> do npm install inside node_modules/mongodb.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: rm -rf can't be used in windows right , what is alternate keyword for cmd ?

Comment: Yes, it won't work in windows. Manually deleting the folder from the directory may help.

Comment: Try doing ` npm install inside node_modules/mongodb` first. See if this one solves the issue.

Comment: thanks man, that was really helpful, But can u explain me , what exactly was wrong ?

Comment: There will be some error during npm install I think. Which one worked for you? First option or the second one?

Comment: npm install inside 'node_modules\mongodb'

Comment: If it helped you, can you accept the answer and up vote it? :)

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `mongoose 4.2.8` into to `package.json` and `npm install` again.
It worked for me locally as well as on heroku.

Answer (score 1):

**what i did**
Just deleted node_modules folder and run

> npm install

it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

definitely it's important to do a:

```
npm install -g node-gyp 
cd /to/your/project-folder
rm -rf node_modules
npm install
```